# Extra claims in Token in web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

The purpose of Token in Web api is to ensure identity of user. Here is the way i created the token.

```
public AuthTokenModel GenerateToken(string UserName, string password, string appCode)
    {
        var tokenExpiration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Convert.ToDouble(GetAppSettingsValue("TokenExpiry")));

        ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("loginId", UserName));
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("password", password));
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("applicationCode", appCode));

        var props = new AuthenticationProperties()
        {
            IssuedUtc = DateTime.UtcNow,
            ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.Add(tokenExpiration),
        };
        var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(identity, props);
        var accessToken = Startup.OAuthOptions.AccessTokenFormat.Protect(ticket);

        AuthTokenModel model = new AuthTokenModel();
        model.AccessToken = string.Format("{0} {1}", "bearer", accessToken);
        model.TokenType = "bearer";
        model.ExpiresIn = tokenExpiration.TotalSeconds.ToString();
        model.Expires = ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc.ToString();
        model.Issued = ticket.Properties.IssuedUtc.ToString();

        return model;
    }
```

and the Model is defined as:

```
public class AuthTokenModel
{
    public string AccessToken { get; set; }

    public string TokenType { get; set; }

    public string ExpiresIn { get; set; }

    public string Issued { get; set; }

    public string Expires { get; set; }
}
```

but i want to know if i add more details of user in Token is the better approach ? and what is the performance if i get the further details from token rather than database.

Comment: Why are you creating claims for passwords?

Comment: Is there anything wrong the way i am doing. please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

1. Never include user's password anywhere. Especially in token.
2. Token, itself, is a very abstract thing. The concept of bearer token
   declares only single idea: anyone in possession of this token could
   use it the same way as others. This token is a kind of user's
   authority confirmation.
3. Implementing your proprietary token-based authentication protocol
   would be not a best choice , because it's a complex work.
4. Take a look at [OAuth2.0](https://oauth.net/2/) / [OpenIDConnect](http://openid.net/connect/) protocols documentation. Consider mature & opensource .net-core *(and previously classic .net framework)*-based solution, implementing this protocols - [IdentityServer](http://identityserver.io/).

I think it would be a great start for understanding tokens-based authentication in web-applications.